# Однородные дополнения

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, однородные-члены, дополнение

Он был в чёрном плаще, шляпе, с тростью в руке и сигарой во рту.
Составного именного сказуемого здесь не видится. Оторванными определениями тоже, кажется, не являются. Остаётся только дополнение. Был в чем, с чем? Очевидно, эти слова все связаны со сказуемым и выполняют одну и ту же функцию, но отвечают на разные вопросы. Но тут может всплыть какой, каков? Но ведь "однородные члены ОБЫЧНО отвечают на один и тот же вопрос". То есть здесь необычная ситуация (вспомним сказуемые). Все другие признаки указывают на однородность (они также соединены сичинительной связью и запятыми - паузами) Дополнения ли это однородные?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Он был в чёрном плаще, шляпе, с тростью в руке и сигарой во рту.***

Это **составное именное сказуемое**, именная часть выражена **предложно-падежными оборотами**, связь между ними однородная сочинительная (союзная и бессоюзная).

Сравнить: *Квартира была без мебели, с балконом.* Пример из учебника Кустовой "Синтаксис современного русского языка".